# PHP. Как многомерный повторяющийся массив представить в виде "плоского" массива (в виде таблицы)?

Tags: php, массивы, дерево

Исходный массив:

```
$arr = array(
    array( 'a' => 'a1', 'child' => array()),

    array( 'a' => 'b1', 'child' => array(
        array( 'a' => 'b2', 'child' => array()),
        array( 'a' => 'b3', 'child' => array())
    )),

    array( 'a' => 'c1', 'child' => array(
        array( 'a' => 'c2', 'child' => array(
            array( 'a' => 'c3', 'child' => array(
                array( 'a' => 'c4', 'child' => array()),
                array( 'a' => 'c5', 'child' => array())
            )),         
            array( 'a' => 'c6', 'child' => array()),
        )),
        array( 'a' => 'c7', 'child' => array())
    )),

    array( 'a' => 'd1', 'child' => array(
        array( 'a' => 'd2', 'child' => array()),
        array( 'a' => 'd3', 'child' => array())
    )),

    array( 'a' => 'e1', 'child' => array(
        array( 'a' => 'e2', 'child' => array()),
        array( 'a' => 'e3', 'child' => array())
    ))
);
```

Вложенность дочерних элементов (глубина вложенности) теоретически может быть бесконечной (на практике до 50-60 штук).
Нужно получить массив вида:

```
$result = array(
    array('a1'),
    array('b1', 'b2'),
    array('b1', 'b3'),
    array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'),
    array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c5'),
    array('c1', 'c2', 'c6'),
    array('c1', 'c7'),
    array('d1', 'd2'),
    array('d1', 'd3'),
    array('e1', 'e2'),
    array('e1', 'e3')
);
```

Т.е. до конечного дочернего элемента в результирующем массиве должны прослеживаться все родительские элементы.

Придумал что-то вроде этого, но все равно не то:

```
function make_table($arr, $level) {
    $level++;
    $child_out = null;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $arr_tmp) {
        $i++;
        $out_tmp[$i][] = $arr_tmp['a'];
        if (count($arr_tmp['child']) > 0) {
            $child_out = make_table($arr_tmp['child'], $level);
        }
        if ($child_out != null) {
            if ($level == 1) {
                $out_tmp[$i] = array_merge($out_tmp[$i], $child_out);
            }
            else
            {
                $out_tmp = array_merge($out_tmp, $child_out);
            }
        }
        $child_out = null;
    }
    return $out_tmp;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(make_table($arr, 0));
echo "</pre>";
```

Всю голову уже переломал... Будут у кого какие мысли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам задал, сам ответил:

```
$table_out = null;
function make_table2($arr, $out_tmp) {
    global $table_out;
    foreach ($arr as $arr_tmp) {
        $tmp = null;
        $tmp[] = $arr_tmp['a'];
        if (count($arr_tmp['child']) > 0) {
            make_table2($arr_tmp['child'], array_merge($out_tmp, $tmp));
        }
        else
        {
            $table_out[] = array_merge($out_tmp, $tmp);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
make_table2($arr, array());
echo "<pre>";
print_r($table_out);
echo "</pre>";
```

Выводит:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => b1
        [1] => b2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => b1
        [1] => b3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => c1
        [1] => c2
        [2] => c3
        [3] => c4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => c1
        [1] => c2
        [2] => c3
        [3] => c5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => c1
        [1] => c2
        [2] => c6
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => c1
        [1] => c7
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => d1
        [1] => d2
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => d1
        [1] => d3
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => e1
        [1] => e2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => e1
        [1] => e3
    )

)
```